# Shiny Gives Error on CSV Upload Due to Encoding in Deployed App Only

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I have a `fileInput("file", label = "Choose CSV File")` element in my ShinyUI, corresponding to a `read.csv()` command in the Server:

```
file <- reactive({
   data <- input$file
   if (is.null(data)){return(NULL)}
   df <- read.csv(data$datapath, header = TRUE, sep=",")
   return(df)
})
```

When I go to upload a UTF-8 encoded CSV file, in the local app, it works correctly. When I publish to ShinyApps.io, I receive an error uploading the same file. *However*, when I convert the file to ANSI, the upload to the hosted app works just fine.

Do apps on ShinyApps.io not accept UTF-8 encoding? Is there something else wrong here?

Comment: Try adding `options(encoding = "UTF-8")`